# Sending the first email is very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp, sendmail, mailkit

I use MailKit (2.5.2) and Google smtp (587 port) for sending emails. (ASP.Net Core 2.2)
   But sending the first email to a previously unknown address (or to which nothing has been sent for a long time) is very, very slow! The message is immediately displayed as sent on my mailbox, but the recipient sees the message only after 5-10m. For example, if I sent a message at 5:00, and in the recipient's box I can only see it at 5:10, while the letter itself says that it was received at 5:00 (10 minutes ago) ...
   Subsequent emails are sent almost instantly. tried test mailboxes on gmail and yahoo.
   Now I have a registration flow with confirmation by mail, and waiting for 5-10 minutes for each new user is a failure.
   What could be the problem?
   I would be grateful for any idea ...

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem is with the server, and not the client. If the message is appearing in your Sent folder on GMail, then it means the client has succeeded in doing its job and whatever time delay exists after that is 100% server dependent.

Unless a Google Engineer decides to respond to your question, you will never get a better answer than this because it would be impossible for anyone to know (we don't get to see GMail's source code).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely recipients' server uses [grey listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) as spam prevention technique.
[ Do not accept first delivery attempt, wait for retry ]
It is AFAIK pretty efficient (so far) against spam botnets.